# Why Express shows cached error message after command: forever cleanlogs?

Tags: node.js, express, forever

I'm running express server using command:

```
     forever -o /var/www/html/expressapp/out.log 
     -e /var/www/html/expressapp/err.log 
     start /var/www/html/expressapp/index.js -w
```

Node v0.8.15

Browser shows very old error message occasionally, but not every time 
when I go to one page which uses jade-template. 
I've fixed the error long time ago but it still appears some times. 
I've tried with different browsers and cleaned every log file in server but I can't get rid of the message. I've changed the file name too..

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed the problem:

```
    app.disable('view cache'); 
    res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=0"); 
    res.setHeader("Expires", new Date(Date.now()).toUTCString());
```